# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V

Tags: java, log4j, propertyconfigurator

When I ran a demo project(proj1) with log4j,it can run successfully.But when I ran the same code in my working project(proj2),it came out this error.Below is the related code:

```
        is = Config.class.getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(is);
```

and the error msg is as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V
at com.esa2000.pdfsign.util.Log4jLoader.loadLog4j(Log4jLoader.java:17)
at com.yinhai.sign.subcenter.PDFSignDemoPublicSeal.main(PDFSignDemoPublicSeal.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

both projects have imported :

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
```

I thought it was the problem of jar package confliction but I tried many ways and failed to solve the problem.Can give me some advices about this issue?Thanks a lot!!

Comment: *Since:
1.2.17* check the version of the jar

Comment: Thank you so much ! After I changed the version to 1.2.17 from 1.2.15,the issue was solved !